# Tail of the maximum of a time-varying Poisson-GP marked process

Tags: extreme-value, poisson-process, pareto-distribution, point-process

Consider a time-varying version of the Poisson-GP marked process on
the real line as commonly used in Peak Over Threshold (POT) modelling
of a variable $Y$. More precisely we have a given time-varying
threshold $u(t)$, and the times $T_i$ of the exceedances over the
threshold follow a non-homogeneous Poisson process with intensity
$\lambda(t)$. When an exceedance occurs at time $t$ we observe the
corresponding mark $Y_{t} > u(t)$ following the three-parameter
[Generalized Pareto (GP)
distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution)
with location $u(t)$, scale $\sigma(t)>0$ and shape $\xi(t)$. The
marks $Y_{T_i}$ are assumed to be independent and to be independent of
the exceedance times $T_i$. The functions $u(t)$, $\sigma(t)$ and
$\xi(t)$ can here be assumed to be smooth, say to have a continuous
$2$-nd order derivative.

Let $M$ be the r.v corresponding to the maximum of the marks $Y_{T_i}$ on an
bounded interval $(a,\,b)$
$$
     M := \max_{\{i: \: a \leqslant T_i \leqslant b\}} \,Y_{T_i}.
$$
It is is not hard to see that
$$ 
 \text{Pr}\{M \leqslant m \} = \exp\left\{ - \int_{a}^{b}
  \lambda(t) \, S_{\texttt{GP}}\{m; u(t),\, \sigma(t),\,\xi(t)\} \,\text{d}t \right\}, 
  \qquad 
  \text{for }m\text{ large}
$$
where $S_{\texttt{GP}}(x;\,\mu, \sigma,\,\xi)$ denotes the survival function
of the GP distribution. In the case where $\lambda(t)$,
$u(t)$, $\sigma(t)$ and $\xi(t)$ are all constant w.r.t. $t$, the maximum
$M$ has a GEV distribution - up to
a probability mass corresponding to the case where no event occurs in the interval.

Let us now on focus on the case where the shape $\xi$ is constant. It
is intuitively clear that the tail behaviour of $M$ depends much on the
value of $\xi$.

In the exponential-tail case where $\xi =0$ and where $\sigma(t)$ has
a single maximum on the interval $(a,\,b)$ we can find an equivalent
for the tail of $M$ a by using Laplace's method. The result depends on
whether the maximum of $\sigma(t)$ occurs at an interior point of the
interval $(a,\,b)$ or at a one of the two boundary points $a$ and  $b$.

My interest is on the case where $\xi < 0$ so that the distribution of
a mark $Y_t$ coming at time $t$ has a *finite* upper end-point $\omega(t) :=
u(t) - \sigma(t) / \xi$.  The upper end-point of the distribution of
$M$ is given by the maximum $\omega_M = \max_t \omega(t)$ which can be
assumed to be unique. Is there any known result about the tail of $M$
in this case?